# Best way to get the word right before a certain word in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

`this is the string and THIS is the word I want`

I've tried using a regex for this:

```
var to_search = "is"
var regex = "/\S+(?="+to_search+")/g";
var matches = string.match(regex);
```

And I wanted matches to contain "THIS" (word that comes after the second if) but it does not seem to be working

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Whats `not working`?

Comment: There isn't a single if in that sentence. Do you mean before the second occurrence of *is*?

Comment: Word or a sequence of non-whitespace symbols? There are two issues right now: 1) the `\s+` must be added after `?=`, and 2) the variable should be passed to RegExp in the constructor notation. Actually, you should get 2 matches. Are you not expecting `this` before `is` and then `THIS`?

Comment: Set *i* case-insensitive flag on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to double backslashes when using the string form of regexes.

Second, you forgot whitespace in your pattern:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\S+\\s+(?="+to_search+")", "g");
```

Comment: regex variable shouldn't be of type *string*.

Comment: In a generic scenario, `to_search` should have its special characters escaped.

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("\\S+(?=\\s+"+to_search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')+")", "ig");`

Answer (score 1):

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a really great site to test your regex and it even generates the code for you.

```js
const regex = /\bis.*(this)/gi;
const str = `this is the string and THIS is the word I want`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```